# Wordpress: the_content filter kills gallery shortcode

Tags: wordpress, plugins, filter, shortcode

My the_content filter kills gallery shortcode and I dont know where the problem is...
I can add just blank the_content filter and gallery disappear from the content and there is just `[gallery]` text. I am using the_content filter:

```
function test($data){
    echo $data;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'test');
```

Any suggestion how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common mistake, you just need to return the information to keep applying new filters, so change the function tho this:

```
function test($data){
    //apply here any content modification then return new content
    return $data;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'test');
```

You can get more information at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Comment: My problem was the ECHO command, not RETURN. That's why it didn't do what I wanted. Thx

Answer (score -1):

You can just pass the modified content within the do_shortcode() to keep the short code functionality working after doing your stuff with the content.

```
add_filter('the_content','your_function');
function your_function($content)
{   
    $content = get_the_content();
    $content = ;// Add your own stuff
    $content = do_shortcode($content);
return $content;    
}
```